# Greasemonkey not working at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, greasemonkey

- Greasemonkey: 2.3
- Firefox: 33.0.3
- Windows: 8

I am not entirely sure if this is the same code used from my other computer running Vista amongst versions of other things due to the death of it, but mostly. It doesn't seem to be working, even if I engineer to be used for other sites.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          hide youtube element
// @namespace     computerarea
// @description   hide div
// @include       https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=*
// @include       https://www.youtube.com/watch?*
// @version       1
// @grant         metadata
// @require       http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.js
// ==/UserScript==


function addJQuery(callback) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("src", "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js");
    script.addEventListener('load', function() {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.textContent = "window.jQQ=jQuery.noConflict(true);(" + callback.toString() + ")();";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }, false);
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}


$(document).ready(function {
$('#watch7-sidebar-contents').hide(0).delay(3000).show(0);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the old version I do believe was working on my other computer as noted, but the one listed 'NEW' is allowing Jquery to work with Tampermonkey again.

http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/157028

```
/*NEW Jquery inject*/
var script = unsafeWindow.document.createElement("SCRIPT");
    script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    unsafeWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    script.addEventListener('load', function(){ 
        jQuery = unsafeWindow['jQuery'];
        unsafeWindow['$_'] = jQuery.noConflict(true);
    }, false);

/*OLD Jquery inject*/
/*function addJQuery(callback) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("src", "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js");
    script.addEventListener('load', function() {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.textContent = "window.jQQ=jQuery.noConflict(true);(" + callback.toString() + ")();";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }, false);
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}*/
```

Comment: Other scripts to inject jquery are as follows: 1. http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/138310 2. http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/168145

Answer (score 0):

**Version 1:**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          hide youtube element
// @namespace     computerarea
// @description   hide div
// @include       https://www.youtube.com/watch?*
// @version       1
// @grant         GM_addStyle
// @require       http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

$('#watch7-sidebar-contents').hide(0).delay(3000).show(0);
```

**Version 2:**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          hide youtube element
// @namespace     computerarea
// @description   hide div
// @include       https://www.youtube.com/watch?*
// @version       2
// @grant         GM_addStyle
// @require       http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js
// @noframes
// ==/UserScript==

//test link example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wygy721nzRc
console.log('working on test link: ' + location.href);
if(window.$) {
    console.log('jQuery loaded; version: ' + window.$.fn.jquery);
    var $sidebar = $('#watch7-sidebar-contents');
    if(!hideAndShow()) {
        console.log('try again after 5sec');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $sidebar = $('#watch7-sidebar-contents');
            hideAndShow();
        }, 5000);
    }
}
else {
    console.log('missing jQuery');
}

function hideAndShow() {
    if($sidebar.length) {
        console.log('hide sidebar, wait for 3sec, and show sidebar again');
        $sidebar.hide(0).delay(3000).show(0);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        console.log('missing sidebar');
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: i dont know why it isnt

Comment: @computerguy Press CTRL+ALT+J in Firefox and paste all console output here, along with your test link.

Comment: the shortcut isnt working but i went to F12 console tab, nothing shows in the console

Comment: @computerguy You didn't provide me with your test link. Anyway, try Version 2 of my answer, use https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wygy721nzRc as a test page and post the console output for me again.